# Dealing with new config files during a system update: right way to use meld?

Tags: updates, diff, meld

I thought about when, during a system update, there is a new config file; let's take this as example (I installed Ubuntu recently, so I didn't still get this prompt):

```
Configuration file `/etc/nscd.conf'
==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
D     : show the differences between the versions
Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
The default action is to keep your current version.
*** nscd.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

From what I find from researches, seems that two variables will be set: `$DPKG_CONFFILE_OLD` and `$DPKG_CONFFILE_NEW`, so to review and merge new entries, is this the right way, using meld by choosing Z (`start a shell to examine the situation`)?

`sudo meld $DPKG_CONFFILE_OLD $DPKG_CONFFILE_NEW` ?

Comment: Meld is a file editor which shows you the differences between two open files. I don’t think it works with variables. You need to open the old and new config files, compare them and merge anything you want from the new into the old. How did you answer the dialogue included in your question?

Comment: If you have never changed the config file from the original default it’s probably best to use the new default